# Data loading issue in Table View in IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a table view controller in my view controller. When I give it static number of rows and cell for row index method name it shows nothing to me in the table view. I have also reload the table view but it isn't showing I don't know why is it so,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell (style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = message.text

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you set `delegate & datasource` for your tableview

Comment: you need to set delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck if u have set

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

Also put a breakpoint on `cellForRowAtIndexpath` to check if code runs through the block.

Also Recheck the cellIdentifier (cellID) is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can u guide me in one short question ? @DHEERAJ

Comment: sure, what is it?

Comment: i have used bridge in my project , i have store value of string in NSUserDefault  now i want to pass it to my swift class , but when i pass it does not show value. @DHEERAJ

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

                //Getting the reference variables of storyboard
                @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!
                var messages = [String]()

                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()


                    //Add some packages
                    messages.append("Super")
                    messages.append("Free ")
                    messages.append("Miscellaneous")
                    messages.append("All ")

                    tableView.datasource = self
                    tableView.delegate = self


                }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell (style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellID")
        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.text

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this . This one works for me

```
  class yourViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.datasource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return messages.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID",for : indexPath)


            let message = messages[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = message.text

            return (cell)

        }
    }
```